# SQL return duplicate records as Distinct records and unique records together

Tags: sql

I am new to SQL and I'm having trouble solving a problem using one table to get two combined results. I have a table that has duplicate entries and individual entries.  I would like my results to show the individual entries and to show the distinct entries of the duplicates.  My table is something like this:

```
Date      Code      Units  
1-1-18    Bottles    12  
1-5-18    Cars       11  
1-2-18    Trains     6  
1-15-18    Boats     9  
1-16-18    Boats     7  
1-15-18    Boats     9  
1-16-18    Plains    8  
1-16-18    Plains    8  
1-16-18    Boats     7  
1-15-18    Boats     9
```

The result I am looking for is:

```
 Date      Code      Units
 1-1-18    Bottles   12
 1-5-18    Cars      11
 1-2-18    Trains    6
 1-15-18   Boats     9
 1-16-18   Plains    8
 1-16-18   Boats     7
```

I've been reading about self joins and `group by` and using `distinct`, but I just can't figure out which clause I need to use.  I think I need to use an aggregate function such as MAX for the Boats and Plains units but I don't know.  If someone could please get me started in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: When you defined the result, can you also let us know how you deduced that result? If you just need distinct ones, you can do select distinct * from table.

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking.  I am trying to eliminate the duplicates and just keep one of the duplicates. But I also want to keep all the individual records as well.

Comment: You answered your own question. Use `GROUP BY` with `MAX()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to your problem:

```
SELECT Date, Code, Units
FROM Table_Name
GROUP BY Date, Code, Units;
```

Since `GROUP BY` will take individual entries and also one of the entries out of duplicate entries.

**OUPUT:**

```
Date        Code     Units
2018-01-01  Bottles  12
2018-01-02  Trains   6
2018-01-05  Cars     11
2018-01-15  Boats    9
2018-01-16  Boats    7
2018-01-16  Plains   8
```

Follow the link for the demo:

> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cPF38vqKPzWrpgkYbGvdLi/0

Comment: Yes I think that is the correct answer, for some reason it did not occur to me that the individual records would be return too.

Comment: If you find it useful please accept it as the answer.

Comment: Isn't `MAX(Units)` missing here?

Comment: No need of max is needed in my opinion since we want only one occurrence of a duplicate record and duplicate record also contains same `Units`.

Comment: I have one more question if you have the time to help me.  If i have 5 columns instead of three, could i still just use three columns in my group by clause or do i need to include all the columns in my table for my group by

Comment: If you want to use 5 columns and selecting all 5 columns then I think you have to use all 5 columns in the group by clause. OR you can use subquery in where clause to remove duplicate using 3 columns and then can select 5 columns in main query.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: To remove duplicate entries.

Comment: You can also do `SELECT Date, Code, Units
FROM Table_Name UNION SELECT Date, Code, Units
FROM Table_Name` to remove duplicates! Or simply `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Comment: @jarlh.. are you really suggest the `union` option over `distinct` or `group by` ?

Comment: @YogeshSharma, sorry, joke/sarcasm. (Too little coffee.)

Answer (score 1):

```
Select distinct date, code, units from yourTable
```

Comment: Yes, I believe your solution will work as well.  For some reason I was thinking Distinct would only return the records that were duplicated, but now I realize it will return individual and duplicates.

Comment: try this. if this works as you want please accept it as answer. If you have another questions ask me.

Comment: `select distinct`, plain and simple!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example or desired result you just need to use `group by` clause to avoid duplication

```
select date, code, units
from table t
group by date, code, units
```

An alternative you could also use `distinct` only

```
select distinct date, code, units
from table t
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to this forum, the pop up tells me that I cant thank you in the comments?  How do I thank people for helping?   I don't want to be rude but I do want to thank everyone for the answers.  I'm a little embarrassed the answer was so obvious.

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved?

Comment: @jarlh.. You can see `distinct` as i have added before any one given the same. Btw from performance perspective i have choosen  `group by`  over `distinct`.